# Strange http response via boost

Tags: c++, boost-asio, httpresponse, boost-beast

Catching error message `http_error_category::bad_reason` as a result of http request via boost. What approximately does this error mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means that parsing the reason did not succeed. E.g by unexpected end of input or illegal character data before the end of line.

The HTTP specification details the characters allowed as part of the first line of a HTTP response, and the code discloses what characters are prohibited in `parse_token_to_eol`.

Notable cause of this error may be when the server doesn't conform to the HTTP specification of requiring CRLF line ends (e.g. sending just `'\n'` instead of `"\r\n"`)

Comment: Cheers. Welcome to [SO]. Please remember to vote/accept https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work